# What are common EE computer tasks?

Tags: simulation, cpu

I am an electrical engineering student looking to build a desktop computer. That being said, I would like to configure it to run common EE tasks as efficiently as possible. Therefore, I am trying to form a list of common EE tasks and the resources they use. I am curious to see if there is anything I missed.

- FPGA development (simulation, synthesis, implementation, ...)

  - Primarily single-threaded (from what I have seen so far). A faster clock speed may actually be noticeable.
  - Very CPU-intensive, almost no graphics
  - A lot of memory/cache space
  - Possibly large amounts of disk I/O (depending on complexity of design)
- Circuit Simulation

  - More graphics-intensive than FPGA development
  - Possibly concurrent, may involve operations such as matrix multiplication and FFT, which could potentially be offloaded to the GPU
  - Less disk I/O
  - Memory depends on circuit complexity and simulation detail
- MCU development

  - IDE is often large and uses a lot of memory
  - The compilation process for small processors shouldn't be too bad, but optimization may take more processing.
  - Little to no GPU usage
  - Is emulation common? If it is, that can be quite complex.
  - Debugging can vary, but I would expect it to not use much processing power since the computation is not happening on the host machine.
- PCB design software
- General mathematical software (Matlab/Octave, SciLab, Sage, ...)

Comment: Welcome to the EE Stack exchange. You might want to have a read of what are the [acceptable topics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for questions. As it stands, this question is rather off topic since it's too broad and essentially a buying recommendation question.

Comment: Makes since @tangrs, should I edit it so that the bottom buying part is removed and the refocus the question on common computational tasks for EE's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, most EE tasks are CPU and memory intensive, but do not generally require high-performance graphics.

However, an EE may find himself doing some mechanical design as well, or even just doing a 3-D view of a PCB design. Running any sort of 3-D display software will benefit from having a good GPU with plenty of display memory.

Make sure you have a good plan for organizing (with revision/release control) and backing up your design data.